# Switching on IObservable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>>

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have the following structure:

```
// source of data
interface IItem
{
    IObservable<string> Changed { get; }
}

interface IItemCollection
{
    List<IItem> Items { get; }
    IObservable<IItem> ItemAdded { get; }
    IObservable<IItem> ItemRemoved { get; }
}

interface IItemCollectionManager
{
    List<IItemCollection> ItemCollectionCollection { get; }
    IObservable<IItemCollection> ItemCollectionAdded { get; }
    IObservable<IItemCollection> ItemCollectionRemoved { get; }
}

// desired result
interface IAggregation
{
    IObservable<string> Changed { get; }
}
```

The goal here, is for `IAggregation` to expose a single observable. However, `IItem`s can be added and removed from each `IItemCollection` at any time, and, indeed, an `IItemCollection` can be added or removed from `IItemCollectionManager` at any time too. Of course, when such an `IItemCollection`is added, `Aggregation` should emit values from that one as well, and if an `ItemCollection` is removed, I no longer want `string`s from the `IItem`s in that collection to be emitted. Also, when an `Item` is added to any `IItemCollection`, values from its `Changed` observable should also produce values out of `IAggregation`'s `Changed` observable.

Now, it was fairly simple solve this problem when there was just a single `IItemCollection`, e.g. like so:

```
class AggregationImpl : IAggregation 
{
    public AggregationImpl(IItemCollection itemCollection)
    {
        var added = itemCollection.ItemAdded
            .Select(_ => itemCollection.Items);
        var removed = itemCollection.ItemRemoved
            .Select(_ => itemCollection.Items);

        Changed = Observable.Merge(added, removed)
            .StartWith(itemCollection.Items)
            .Select(coll => coll.Select(item => item.Changed).Merge())
            .Switch();
    }

    public IObservable<string> Changed { get; }

}
```

... the key point here being that I flatten out all the `Item`'s `Changed` observables into a single observable with `Merge()`and then, each time an item is added or removed, I recreate the whole `Observable` and use `Switch()` to unsubscribe from the old and subscribe to the new`.

I feel like expanding to include the `IItemCollectionManager` should be quite straightforward, but I'm not quite sure how to approach it.

Comment: The interface `IItem` and `IAggregation` is the same, is that intended?

Comment: Is it an option to use `SelectMany()`?

Comment: @Program. Yes, intended. There is a third party that wishes to consume `IAggregation`s observable, however `IAggregation` must do the work of emitting values from the correct `Item`s, regardless of when they appear and disappear (even if that means an item is added or removed, or an entire collection of items is added or removed).

Comment: @Progman. Everything in `System.Reactive.Linq` is an option - it's assembling them together in a useful way that's tricky in this instance. `SelectMany` will not work just by itself. I'm almost certain I need at least one `Switch()` to get this to work.

Comment: Can you use `SourceList` from [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData)? Since you are working with lists and Rx you might want to take a look at this library.

Comment: @Progman Unfortunately, DynamicData doesn't seem to address my problem, but an interesting library nonetheless :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this works, or at least sets you down the right path. As testing it seems rather involved, I'm going to wing it. If you have some easy test code, then I'll be happy to test.

First, I don't really like your posted implementation. You're hooking into the `ItemAdded` and `ItemRemoved` obeservables, without using the data at all; you're getting the data from the `Items` property. This can lead to a race condition in a poor implementation, where the event is sent out before the property is updated. I therefore created my own implementation. I also recommend throwing it into an extension method, because that makes life easier later:

```
public static IObservable<string> ToAggregatedObservable(this IItemCollection itemCollection)
{
    return Observable.Merge(
            itemCollection.ItemAdded.Select(item => (op: "+", item)),
            itemCollection.ItemRemoved.Select(item => (op: "-", item))
        )
        .Scan(ImmutableList<IItem>.Empty.AddRange(itemCollection.Items), (list, t) =>
            t.op == "+"
                ? list.Add(t.item)
                : list.Remove(t.item)
        )
        .Select(l => l.Select(item => item.Changed).Merge())
        .Switch();

}
```

Forgive the magic string for a second, you can turn it into an `enum` if you like. We maintain the state of the current items in an `ImmutableList` inside `Scan`. When an item gets added/removed, we update the list, then switch the observable.

This same logic can be applied to the collection manager level:

```
public static IObservable<string> ToAggregatedObservable(this IItemCollectionManager itemCollectionManager)
{
    return Observable.Merge(
            itemCollectionManager.ItemCollectionAdded.Select(itemColl => (op: "+", itemColl)),
            itemCollectionManager.ItemCollectionRemoved.Select(itemColl => (op: "-", itemColl))
        )
        .Scan(ImmutableList<IItemCollection>.Empty.AddRange(itemCollectionManager.ItemCollectionCollection), (list, t) =>
            t.op == "+"
                ? list.Add(t.itemColl)
                : list.Remove(t.itemColl)
        )
        .Select(l => l.Select(itemColl => itemColl.ToAggregatedObservable()).Merge())
        .Switch();
}
```

Here we're just re-using the first extension method, and using the same adding/removing then switch logic as before.

Comment: I realized there was a flaw in that items previously added to the collection (or manager) before observable hookup were ignored. That's fixed now by adding them to the initialization of the `.Scan` function call.

Comment: This looks very promising @Shlomo. I'll try this out shortly, but it definitly looks like you've managed to figure out where to put the final `Switch()`. Looks right. Although there are tests against the potential race conditions, I did agree with you and changed my implementation yesterday. I do have one question though, maybe you have an opinion. Largely, this implementation replaces events. I find that the constant bookkeeping of `Item`s is just clutter, but these types or not immutable per se (although the relevant parts are). Do you think it's bad practice to expose them as observables?

Comment: I'm not really following the question, sorry. Do I think it's bad practice to expose what as observables?

Comment: I’m thinking specifically of types that are mutable. An Item is mutable, and the Added and Removed observables are basically replacing equivalent events. There seems to be some consensus that, for IObservable<T>, T should me entirely immutable. However, then it becomes difficult to replace all cases of events with observables. Is it an iron rule to not emit values that are mutable (i.e. stick to events)?

Comment: Rx is a library for primarily modeling events. Events don't change. So I would say it is a good practice, but certainly not 'iron rule'. The main downside to a mutable `T` is that if you have multiple subscriptions, one of the subscriptions can mutate the `T` objects meaning that not all subscriptions are seeing the same thing. The short answer I would come back to though is, if you're modeling events, and events don't change, why do you have a mutable object?